# Upgrade to Mavericks from an external HDD

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, upgrade, external-disk

I have Snow Leopard on and external HDD. Is it possible to boot form the external drive, and install Mavericks on the internal drive via the Mac App Store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is entirely possible. Download Mavericks from the Mac App Store and in the install process select your internal disk as the destination for the install.